# War Card Game in C, Implementing Linked Lists, Segmentation Error when shuffling deck and distributing cards to players

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc

I am having a couple problems with this code that I am working on for a school assignment. I was wondering if anyone with more experience can point me towards the errors in my code so I can fix them. At this point I am trying to shuffle the deck using rand() (My professor instructed us to do so) and move the card from the linked List for the deck into the players hand. Unfortunately I also get segmentation errors. The debugger points the error towards the  insertBackDeck() function. I have posted both the full function below and the playRound() and insertBackDeck() that messes me up.

```
//Name:
//Dr. Steinberg
//COP3502 Spring 2022
//Programming Assignment 3 Skeleton

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct card_s{
    int rank;    //number
    char * type; //type of card
    struct card_s * nextptr;
}card_t;

//function prototypes
void rules(); //display rules
int playRound(); //simulate round
card_t * openCardDeck(); //open the card deck and place into a linkedlist setup
card_t * insertBackSetup(card_t *node, char *name, int cardrank); //take card from orginial deck and place in back of linked list for setup of game
int empty(card_t * node); //check to see if linked list is empty
void cleanUp(card_t * head); //free memory to prevent memory leaks
int deckSize(card_t * head); //count number of nodes in the linked list
card_t * search(card_t * node, int spot); //search list for a specific spot in the card deck indexing is similar to array setup
card_t * copyCard(card_t * node); //make a deep copy of card
card_t * removeCard(card_t * node, int spot); //remove card from linkedlist
card_t * insertBackDeck(card_t *head, card_t *node); //place card at end of pile
int compareCard(card_t * cardp1, card_t * cardp2); //compare cards
card_t * moveCardBack(card_t *head); //place card at top of deck to the bottom of the deck

int main()
{
    int seed;
    printf("Enter Seed: ");
    scanf("%d", &seed);
    
    srand(seed); //seed set
    rules();
    
    int player; //1 or 2
    int result;
    
    printf("Would you like to be player 1 or 2?\n");
    printf("Enter 1 or 2: ");
    scanf("%d", &player); //choose player
    
    for(int game = 1; game <= 5; ++game) //simulate games
    {
        printf("Alright lets play game %d.\n", game);
        printf("Lets split the deck.\n");

        result = playRound(); //play game
        
        if((result == 1 && player == 1) || (result == 2 && player == 2)) //determine who won
            printf("You won game %d.\n", game);
        else
            printf("I won game %d.\n", game);
    }
    
    return 0;
}

void rules()
{
    printf("Welcome to the card game war!\n");
    printf("Here are the rules.\n");
    printf("You have a pile of cards and I have a pile of cards.\n");
    printf("We will each pull the top card off of our respective deck and compare them.\n");
    printf("The card with the highest number will win the round and take both cards.\n");
    printf("However if there is a tie, then we have to we have to place one card faced down and the next one faced up and compare the results.\n");
    printf("Winner of the tie, will grab all the cards out. However if it's a tie again, then we repeat the same action.\n");
    printf("Ready? Here we go!\n");
}

int playRound()
{
    card_t *head = openCardDeck();
    card_t *p1Deck = NULL;
    card_t *p2Deck = NULL;
    //card_t *temp;
    printf("There are %d cards in the deck.", deckSize(head));
    while(deckSize(head) != 0)
    {
        int spot = rand() % deckSize(head);
        insertBackDeck(p1Deck, copyCard(search(head, spot)));
        head = removeCard(head, spot);
        spot = rand() % deckSize(head);
        insertBackDeck(p2Deck, copyCard(search(head, spot)));
        head = removeCard(head, spot);
        //printf("Player 1 pulled %s",p1Deck->type);
    }
    printf("Test");
    return 1;
}

card_t * openCardDeck()
{
    FILE *fptr = fopen("deck.txt", "r");
    
    char *name = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
    
    if (name == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error in malloc...\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    card_t * head = NULL;
    
    int cardrank = 13;
    int tracker = 1;
    while(fscanf(fptr, "%s", name) == 1)
    {           
        strcat(name, " ");
        
        if(tracker % 5 == 1)
        {
            strcat(name, "of Clubs");
            head = insertBackSetup(head, name, cardrank);
        }
        else if(tracker % 5 == 2)
        {
            strcat(name, "of Diamonds");
            head = insertBackSetup(head, name, cardrank);
        }
        else if(tracker % 5 == 3)
        {
            strcat(name, "of Hearts");
            head = insertBackSetup(head, name, cardrank);
        }
        else if(tracker % 5 == 4)
        {
            strcat(name, "of Spades");
            head = insertBackSetup(head, name, cardrank);
            tracker = 0;
            --cardrank;
        }
        
        ++tracker;
        
    }
    
    free(name);
    fclose(fptr);
    
    return head;
}

card_t * insertBackSetup(card_t *node, char *name, int cardrank)
{
    
    if(empty(node)) //check to see if list is empty
    {
        node = (card_t *) malloc(sizeof(card_t));
        
        if(empty(node)) //check to see if malloc worked
        {
            printf("Did not allocate head successfully...");
            printf("Program Terminating...\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        else //otherwise populate data of new head node
        {
            node->type = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
            
            if(node->type == NULL)
            {
                printf("Error with malloc...\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            
            strcpy(node->type, name);
            node->rank = cardrank;
            node->nextptr = NULL; //must make new tail nextptr NULL!!!
            
            return node;  //terminate
        }
      
    }
    
    //here we know that the list has at least one node
    
    card_t *head = node; //keep pointer to head since we will need to return this address
    
    while(node->nextptr != NULL) //traverse to tail
        node = node->nextptr;
    
    node->nextptr = (card_t *) malloc(sizeof(card_t)); 
    
    if(node->nextptr == NULL) //see if new tail was allocated successfully
    {
        printf("Did not allocate node successfully...");
        return head; //terminate if tail didn't get created
    }
    
    //populate new node
    node->nextptr->type = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
    
    if(node->nextptr->type == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error with malloc...\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    strcpy(node->nextptr->type, name); // THIS IS KHAN'S ASSIGNMENTS HOWD YOU GET IT
    node->nextptr->rank = cardrank;
    node->nextptr->nextptr = NULL; //very important
            
    return head; //return head node since we need our starting point of the linked list
}

int empty(card_t * node)
{
    return (node == NULL); //return condition result
}

void cleanUp(card_t * head)
{
    card_t* temp;
    while(head->nextptr != NULL)
    {
        temp = head;
        head = head->nextptr;
        free(temp);
    }
    
}

int deckSize(card_t * head)
{
    int count = 0;
    card_t* temp;
    temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->nextptr;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}


card_t * search(card_t * node, int spot)
{
    int i = 0;
    card_t *temp = node;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        if(i == spot)
            return temp;
        i++;
        temp = temp->nextptr;
    }
    printf("error");
    return node;
}

card_t * copyCard(card_t * node)
{
    if(node == NULL)
        return NULL;
    card_t* copy = (card_t*)malloc(sizeof(card_t));
    copy->nextptr = NULL;
    copy->rank = node->rank;
    copy->type = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(node->type) + 1));
    strcpy(copy->type, node->type);
    return copy;
}

card_t * removeCard(card_t * node, int spot)
{
    if(empty(node))
        return NULL;
    card_t * head = node;
    card_t * temp = search(node, spot);
    if(temp == NULL)
        return head;
    if(head == temp)
    {
        head = head->nextptr;
        free(temp);
        return head;
    }
    while(head->nextptr != temp)
        head = head->nextptr;
    head->nextptr = temp->nextptr;
    free(temp);
    return head;
}

card_t * insertBackDeck(card_t *head, card_t *node)
{
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = node;
        head->nextptr = NULL;
        return head;
    }   
    card_t * temp;
    temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->nextptr;
    }
    temp = node;
    return head;
}

int compareCard(card_t * cardp1, card_t * cardp2)
{
    if(cardp1 == NULL && cardp2 != NULL)
        return 2;
    if(cardp1 != NULL && cardp2 == NULL)
        return 1;
    if(cardp1 == NULL && cardp2 == NULL)
        return 0;
    if(cardp1->rank == cardp2->rank)
        return 0;
    if(cardp1->rank > cardp2->rank)
        return 1;
    if(cardp1->rank< cardp2->rank)
        return 2;
    return 3;
}

card_t * moveCardBack(card_t *head)
{
    if(head == NULL)
        return NULL;
    card_t *front = head; card_t *last = head;
    while(last->nextptr != NULL)
        last = last->nextptr;
    last->nextptr = head;
    head = front->nextptr;
    front->nextptr = NULL;
    return head;
}
```

EDIT: I updated the code and posted it below. The error I get is when I use the printf.

```
//Name:
//Dr. Steinberg
//COP3502 Spring 2022
//Programming Assignment 3 Skeleton

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct card_s{
    int rank;    //number
    char * type; //type of card
    struct card_s * nextptr;
}card_t;

//function prototypes
void rules(); //display rules
int playRound(); //simulate round
card_t * openCardDeck(); //open the card deck and place into a linkedlist setup
card_t * insertBackSetup(card_t *node, char *name, int cardrank); //take card from orginial deck and place in back of linked list for setup of game
int empty(card_t * node); //check to see if linked list is empty
void cleanUp(card_t * head); //free memory to prevent memory leaks
int deckSize(card_t * head); //count number of nodes in the linked list
card_t * search(card_t * node, int spot); //search list for a specific spot in the card deck indexing is similar to array setup
card_t * copyCard(card_t * node); //make a deep copy of card
card_t * removeCard(card_t * node, int spot); //remove card from linkedlist
card_t * insertBackDeck(card_t *head, card_t *node); //place card at end of pile
int compareCard(card_t * cardp1, card_t * cardp2); //compare cards
card_t * moveCardBack(card_t *head); //place card at top of deck to the bottom of the deck

int main()
{
    int seed;
    printf("Enter Seed: ");
    scanf("%d", &seed);
    
    srand(seed); //seed set
    rules();
    
    int player; //1 or 2
    int result;
    
    printf("Would you like to be player 1 or 2?\n");
    printf("Enter 1 or 2: ");
    scanf("%d", &player); //choose player
    
    for(int game = 1; game <= 5; ++game) //simulate games
    {
        printf("Alright lets play game %d.\n", game);
        printf("Lets split the deck.\n");

        result = playRound(); //play game
        
        if((result == 1 && player == 1) || (result == 2 && player == 2)) //determine who won
            printf("You won game %d.\n", game);
        else
            printf("I won game %d.\n", game);
    }
    
    return 0;
}

void rules()
{
    printf("Welcome to the card game war!\n");
    printf("Here are the rules.\n");
    printf("You have a pile of cards and I have a pile of cards.\n");
    printf("We will each pull the top card off of our respective deck and compare them.\n");
    printf("The card with the highest number will win the round and take both cards.\n");
    printf("However if there is a tie, then we have to we have to place one card faced down and the next one faced up and compare the results.\n");
    printf("Winner of the tie, will grab all the cards out. However if it's a tie again, then we repeat the same action.\n");
    printf("Ready? Here we go!\n");
}

int playRound()
{
    card_t *head = openCardDeck();
    card_t *p1Deck = NULL;
    card_t *p2Deck = NULL;
    int deckSized = deckSize(head);
    printf("There are %d cards in the deck.", deckSized);
    while(deckSized != 0)
    {
        int spot = rand() % deckSized;
        insertBackDeck(p1Deck, search(head, spot));
        head = removeCard(head, spot);
        deckSized--;
        spot = rand() % deckSized;
        insertBackDeck(p2Deck, search(head, spot));
        head = removeCard(head, spot);
        deckSized--;
        printf("Player 1 pulled %s",p1Deck->type);
    }
    printf("Test");
    return 1;
}

card_t * openCardDeck()
{
    FILE *fptr = fopen("deck.txt", "r");
    
    char *name = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
    
    if (name == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error in malloc...\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    card_t * head = NULL;
    
    int cardrank = 13;
    int tracker = 1;
    while(fscanf(fptr, "%s", name) == 1)
    {           
        strcat(name, " ");
        
        if(tracker % 5 == 1)
        {
            strcat(name, "of Clubs");
            head = insertBackSetup(head, name, cardrank);
        }
        else if(tracker % 5 == 2)
        {
            strcat(name, "of Diamonds");
            head = insertBackSetup(head, name, cardrank);
        }
        else if(tracker % 5 == 3)
        {
            strcat(name, "of Hearts");
            head = insertBackSetup(head, name, cardrank);
        }
        else if(tracker % 5 == 4)
        {
            strcat(name, "of Spades");
            head = insertBackSetup(head, name, cardrank);
            tracker = 0;
            --cardrank;
        }
        
        ++tracker;
        
    }
    
    free(name);
    fclose(fptr);
    
    return head;
}

card_t * insertBackSetup(card_t *node, char *name, int cardrank)
{
    
    if(empty(node)) //check to see if list is empty
    {
        node = (card_t *) malloc(sizeof(card_t));
        
        if(empty(node)) //check to see if malloc worked
        {
            printf("Did not allocate head successfully...");
            printf("Program Terminating...\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        else //otherwise populate data of new head node
        {
            node->type = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
            
            if(node->type == NULL)
            {
                printf("Error with malloc...\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            
            strcpy(node->type, name);
            node->rank = cardrank;
            node->nextptr = NULL; //must make new tail nextptr NULL!!!
            
            return node;  //terminate
        }
      
    }
    
    //here we know that the list has at least one node
    
    card_t *head = node; //keep pointer to head since we will need to return this address
    
    while(node->nextptr != NULL) //traverse to tail
        node = node->nextptr;
    
    node->nextptr = (card_t *) malloc(sizeof(card_t)); 
    
    if(node->nextptr == NULL) //see if new tail was allocated successfully
    {
        printf("Did not allocate node successfully...");
        return head; //terminate if tail didn't get created
    }
    
    //populate new node
    node->nextptr->type = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
    
    if(node->nextptr->type == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error with malloc...\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    strcpy(node->nextptr->type, name); // THIS IS KHAN'S ASSIGNMENTS HOWD YOU GET IT
    node->nextptr->rank = cardrank;
    node->nextptr->nextptr = NULL; //very important
            
    return head; //return head node since we need our starting point of the linked list
}

int empty(card_t * node)
{
    return (node == NULL); //return condition result
}

void cleanUp(card_t * head)
{
    card_t* temp;
    while(head->nextptr != NULL)
    {
        temp = head;
        head = head->nextptr;
        free(temp);
    }
    
}

int deckSize(card_t * head)
{
    int count = 0;
    card_t* temp;
    temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->nextptr;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}


card_t * search(card_t * node, int spot)
{
    int i = 0;
    card_t *temp = node;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        if(i == spot)
            return temp;
        i++;
        temp = temp->nextptr;
    }
    printf("error");
    return node;
}

card_t * copyCard(card_t * node)
{
    if(node == NULL)
        return NULL;
    card_t* copy = (card_t*)malloc(sizeof(card_t));
    copy->nextptr = NULL;
    copy->rank = node->rank;
    copy->type = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(node->type) + 1));
    strcpy(copy->type, node->type);
    return copy;
}

card_t * removeCard(card_t * node, int spot)
{
    if(empty(node))
        return NULL;
    card_t * head = node;
    card_t * temp = search(node, spot);
    if(temp == NULL)
        return head;
    if(head == temp)
    {
        head = head->nextptr;
        free(temp);
        return head;
    }
    while(head->nextptr != temp)
        head = head->nextptr;
    head->nextptr = temp->nextptr;
    free(temp);
    return node;
}

card_t * insertBackDeck(card_t *head, card_t *node)
{
    card_t *newCard = copyCard(node);
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = newCard;
        head->nextptr = NULL;
        return head;
    }   
    card_t * temp;
    temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->nextptr;
    }
    temp = newCard;
    return head;
}

int compareCard(card_t * cardp1, card_t * cardp2)
{
    if(cardp1 == NULL && cardp2 != NULL)
        return 2;
    if(cardp1 != NULL && cardp2 == NULL)
        return 1;
    if(cardp1 == NULL && cardp2 == NULL)
        return 0;
    if(cardp1->rank == cardp2->rank)
        return 0;
    if(cardp1->rank > cardp2->rank)
        return 1;
    if(cardp1->rank< cardp2->rank)
        return 2;
    return 3;
}

card_t * moveCardBack(card_t *head)
{
    if(head == NULL)
        return NULL;
    card_t *front = head; card_t *last = head;
    while(last->nextptr != NULL)
        last = last->nextptr;
    last->nextptr = head;
    head = front->nextptr;
    front->nextptr = NULL;
    return head;
}
```

This is the deck.txt

```
Ace
Ace
Ace
Ace
King
King
King
King
Queen
Queen
Queen
Queen
Jack
Jack
Jack
Jack
10
10
10
10
9
9
9
9
8
8
8
8
7
7
7
7
6
6
6
6
5
5
5
5
4
4
4
4
3
3
3
3
2
2
2
2
```

Comment: [Pay attention to your compiler warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/x3fKxzrc1), and if you don't see any its because they're not turned up high enough. Ex: Look a `deckSize` and ask yourself what value `count` has *before* going into that loop. (hint: the only valid answer is 'i have no idea', and it would be agreement with your code, because it doesn't either. the value is *indeterminate* because you never initialized `count`). Pouring salt on the wound, `playRound` claims it returns an `int`, but never does (though its only caller certainly expects it to).

Comment: you got 'deck.txt'?

Comment: Just added it in the main post. I can't really make changes on that as that is the Professor gave the file.

Answer (score 0):

my compiler immediately complains about this

```
card_t *head = openCardDeck();
card_t *p1Deck;  <<<<<<<<<<<<<=========================
card_t *p2Deck;
card_t *temp;
printf("There are %d cards in the deck.", deckSize(head));
int deckSized = deckSize(head);
while(deckSized != 0)
{
    int spot = rand() % deckSized;
    insertBackDeck(p1Deck, search(head, spot)); <<<<<<<==========
```

p1Deck is unititlaized. You need

```
     card_t* p1Deck = NULL;
```

likewise you have

```
int deckSize(card_t* head)
{
    int count; <<<<===============================
    card_t* temp;
    temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->nextptr;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

also 'search' doesnt return a value. Nor does 'campareCard' or 'playRound'

All these were errors or warnings from my compiler. Pay attention to the messages from the compiler, it is trying to help you

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed the compiler issues, unfortunately my program still doesn't run all the way and I still think the problem is due to the insertBackSetup() or maybe search().

Comment: post updated code (in the original question, add it to the end)- so I can see what you have changed

Comment: Hey, I just added the updated code it runs fine the moment I remove the printf, but I need to implement the whole playRound with a select output so I will be needing the printf. I think that my p1Deck and p2Deck linked lists are the problem, and I am trying to see if the code really gave each player 26 cards out of the 52 in the deck.

Answer (score 0):

Ok in playRound you do this

```
 insertBackDeck(p1Deck, search(head, spot));
```

you are clearly hoping that insertBackDeck will update p1Deck because you use it a few lines later (it was NULL)

```
  printf("Player 1 pulled %s", p1Deck->type);
```

In fact insertBAckDeck return a new valid card pointer but you ignore it.

You need to do

```
 p1Deck = insertBackDeck(p1Deck, search(head, spot));
```

Alternatively, you could have had insertBAckDeck update p1Deck in place by passing it using 'c style pass by reference'

But mainly - learn to use your debugger. A program this size is hard to debug without one, it is very simple using a debugger

anyway when I fix that it runs to the end and produces lots of text, dont know if its correct

Comment: Total oversight on my part, I appreciate the help. I don't know why I didn't catch that. Anyways, the p1Deck and p2Deck only hold one card each, I'm not too sure why. I tried drawing out the logic for my insertBackDeck, but from my viewpoint everything is right.